# Extract the first N elements of a binary in Erlang

Tags: split, erlang

Can someone please tell me how to get the first 4 characters in the following binary list in Erlang:

```
<<245,185,198,200,52,227,138,93,250>>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [Bit Syntax](http://erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/bit_syntax.html):

```
<< R:4/binary,_/binary >> = <<245,185,198,200,52,227,138,93,250>>.
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. It gives me this <<"õ¹ÆÈ">>. but I need something like this. <<245,185,198,200>>

Comment: @hasi these two are exactly the same values, `õ¹ÆÈ` is `245,185,198,200` encoded in UTF-8. Just check it by `<<245,185,198,200>> =:= <<"õ¹ÆÈ">>`.

Comment: @hasi, Your question says, *Can someone please tell me how to get the first 4 **characters***..." And, now you say you want integers?! `io:format("~w~n", [R]).` => 
`<<245,185,198,200>>`

Comment: @7stud Thanks for the comment. I have done a mistake in my question.

Answer (score 0):

there is two ways:

1)

split binary to list -

```
[245,185,198,200,52,227,138,93,250] = binary_to_list(<<245,185,198,200,52,227,138,93,250>>).
{"õ¹ÆÈ",[52,227,138,93,250]} = lists:split(4, [245,185,198,200,52,227,138,93,250]).
```

2)

or get the direct binary part

```
<<"õ¹ÆÈ">> = binary:part(<<245,185,198,200,52,227,138,93,250>>, 0, 4).
```

3)

if you need exact 4 numbers - you may use this function

```
[A, B, C, D | _Tail] = binary_to_list(<<245,185,198,200,52,227,138,93,250>>).

2> A.
245
3> B.
185
4> C.
198
5> D
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. It gives me this <<"õ¹ÆÈ">>. but I need something like this. <<245,185,198,200>>

Answer (score 0):

```
1> M = <<245,185,198,200,52,227,138,93,250>>.
<<245,185,198,200,52,227,138,93,250>>
2> <<A,B,C,D, _/binary>> = M.
<<245,185,198,200,52,227,138,93,250>>
3> A.
245
4> B.
185
5> C.
198
6> D.
200
7>
```